# string-trim does not work on global variable

Tags: string, lisp, common-lisp, trim

Why string-trim does not work on global variable in Common Lisp?

```lisp
(defvar *whitespaces* '(#\Space #\Newline #\Backspace #\Tab
                        #\Linefeed #\Page #\Return #\Rubout))
(defvar *str* "Hello     World")

(defun trim (s)
  (string-trim *whitespaces* s))

(print (trim *str*))
;; output "Hello     World"
```

Comment: A function gets argument objects passed. A function does never see where the object comes from. Thus a function cannot see and does not care whether the object was or is bound by global variable.

Answer (score 6):

As said in the [manual](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_stg_tr.htm#string-trim):

> `string-trim` returns a substring of string, with all characters in character-bag stripped off the beginning and end.

So,

```
CL-USER> (defvar *str* "   Hello     World     ")
*STR*
CL-USER> (trim *str*)
"Hello     World"
```

If you want to remove all the space character between words you can use some library, for instance [`cl-str`](https://github.com/vindarel/cl-str/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=ios_app&utm_name=iossmf):

```
CL-USER> (ql:quickload "str")
...
CL-USER> (str:collapse-whitespaces *str*)
"Hello World"
T
```

Comment: I just want to remove trailing whitespaces from string. I misunderstand the the functionality of ```string-trim```.

Comment: @nevzatseferoglu If you want only leading, or trailing, characters trimmed, you can use `string-left-trim` and `string-right-trim` to get just one end of the string trimmed.